# Boost ASIO deserialization wrong values

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, boost-serialization

when I try to deserialize a struct on the server, I am receiving incorrect values from initial transmission. I created a struct with member variables of the same type (2 and 1); however, when transmitting receive zeros and unsure why.
Does the incoming data in connection.hpp need to be of the same type, which I am sending?  Any suggestions ?

Client:

```
 #include <boost/asio.hpp>
    #include <boost/bind.hpp>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>
    #include "connection.hpp" // Must come before boost/serialization headers.
    #include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
    #include "info.hpp"
    
class client
{
public:
  /// Constructor starts the asynchronous connect operation.
  client(boost::asio::io_service& io_service,
      const std::string& host, const std::string& service)
    : connection_(io_service)
  {

    Packet p;
    p.a = 2;
    p.b = 1;
    packet_.push_back(p);
    // Resolve the host name into an IP address.
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query(host, service);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator =
      resolver.resolve(query);

    // Start an asynchronous connect operation.
    boost::asio::async_connect(connection_.socket(), endpoint_iterator,
        boost::bind(&client::handle_connect, this,
          boost::asio::placeholders::error));
  }

  /// Handle completion of a connect operation.
  void handle_connect(const boost::system::error_code& e)
  {
    if (!e)
    {
     
      connection_.async_write(packet_,
          boost::bind(&client::handle_write, this,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }
    else
    {
      
      std::cerr << e.message() << std::endl;
    }
  }

  void handle_write(const boost::system::error_code& e)
  {
 
  }

private:
  connection connection_;

  std::vector<Packet> packet_;
};

} 

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  try
  {
    // Check command line arguments.
    if (argc != 3)
    {
      std::cerr << "Usage: client <host> <port>" << std::endl;
      return 1;
    }

    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    s11n_example::client client(io_service, argv[1], argv[2]);
    io_service.run();
  }
  catch (std::exception& e)
  {
    std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Info:

```
#ifndef Packet_HPP
#define Packet_HPP


namespace s11n_example {

struct Packet
{
 int a;
 int b; 

  template <typename Archive>
  void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version)
  {
    int a;
    int b;
  }
};

} // namespace s11n_example

#endif
```

Server:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "connection.hpp" // Must come before boost/serialization headers.
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include "info.hpp"
namespace s11n_example {

/// Serves stock quote information to any client that connects to it.
class server
{
public:
  /// Constructor opens the acceptor and starts waiting for the first incoming
  /// connection.
  server(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, unsigned short port)
    : acceptor_(io_service,
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), port))
  {
    // Create the data to be sent to each client.
   

    // Start an accept operation for a new connection.
    connection_ptr new_conn(new connection(acceptor_.get_io_service()));
    acceptor_.async_accept(new_conn->socket(),
        boost::bind(&server::handle_accept, this,
          boost::asio::placeholders::error, new_conn));
  }

  /// Handle completion of a accept operation.
  void handle_accept(const boost::system::error_code& e, connection_ptr conn)
  {
    if (!e)
    {
     
      conn->async_read(packet_,
          boost::bind(&server::handle_read, this,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error, conn));
    }

    // Start an accept operation for a new connection.
    connection_ptr new_conn(new connection(acceptor_.get_io_service()));
    acceptor_.async_accept(new_conn->socket(),
        boost::bind(&server::handle_accept, this,
          boost::asio::placeholders::error, new_conn));
  }

  /// Handle completion of a write operation.
  void handle_read(const boost::system::error_code& e, connection_ptr conn)
  {

       // Print out the data that was received.
      for (std::size_t i = 0; i < packet_.size(); ++i) 
        std::cout << packet_[i].a << "\n";

  }

private:
  /// The acceptor object used to accept incoming socket connections.
  boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor_;

  /// The data to be sent to each client.
  std::vector<Packet> packet_;
};

} // namespace s11n_example

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  try
  {
    // Check command line arguments.
    if (argc != 2)
    {
      std::cerr << "Usage: server <port>" << std::endl;
      return 1;
    }
    unsigned short port = boost::lexical_cast<unsigned short>(argv[1]);

    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    s11n_example::server server(io_service, port);
    io_service.run();
  }
  catch (std::exception& e)
  {
    std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Connection

```
#ifndef SERIALIZATION_CONNECTION_HPP
#define SERIALIZATION_CONNECTION_HPP

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

namespace s11n_example {

/// The connection class provides serialization primitives on top of a socket.
/**
 * Each message sent using this class consists of:
 * @li An 8-byte header containing the length of the serialized data in
 * hexadecimal.
 * @li The serialized data.
 */
class connection
{
public:
  /// Constructor.
  connection(boost::asio::io_service& io_service)
    : socket_(io_service)
  {
  }

  /// Get the underlying socket. Used for making a connection or for accepting
  /// an incoming connection.
  boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket& socket()
  {
    return socket_;
  }

  /// Asynchronously write a data structure to the socket.
  template <typename T, typename Handler>
  void async_write(const T& t, Handler handler)
  {
    // Serialize the data first so we know how large it is.
    std::ostringstream archive_stream;
    boost::archive::text_oarchive archive(archive_stream);
    archive << t;
    outbound_data_ = archive_stream.str();

    // Format the header.
    std::ostringstream header_stream;
    header_stream << std::setw(header_length)
      << std::hex << outbound_data_.size();
    if (!header_stream || header_stream.str().size() != header_length)
    {
      // Something went wrong, inform the caller.
      boost::system::error_code error(boost::asio::error::invalid_argument);
      socket_.get_io_service().post(boost::bind(handler, error));
      return;
    }
    outbound_header_ = header_stream.str();

    // Write the serialized data to the socket. We use "gather-write" to send
    // both the header and the data in a single write operation.
    std::vector<boost::asio::const_buffer> buffers;
    buffers.push_back(boost::asio::buffer(outbound_header_));
    buffers.push_back(boost::asio::buffer(outbound_data_));
    boost::asio::async_write(socket_, buffers, handler);
  }

  /// Asynchronously read a data structure from the socket.
  template <typename T, typename Handler>
  void async_read(T& t, Handler handler)
  {
    // Issue a read operation to read exactly the number of bytes in a header.
    void (connection::*f)(
        const boost::system::error_code&,
        T&, boost::tuple<Handler>)
      = &connection::handle_read_header<T, Handler>;
    boost::asio::async_read(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(inbound_header_),
        boost::bind(f,
          this, boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::ref(t),
          boost::make_tuple(handler)));
  }

  /// Handle a completed read of a message header. The handler is passed using
  /// a tuple since boost::bind seems to have trouble binding a function object
  /// created using boost::bind as a parameter.
  template <typename T, typename Handler>
  void handle_read_header(const boost::system::error_code& e,
      T& t, boost::tuple<Handler> handler)
  {
    if (e)
    {
      boost::get<0>(handler)(e);
    }
    else
    {
      // Determine the length of the serialized data.
      std::istringstream is(std::string(inbound_header_, header_length));
      std::size_t inbound_data_size = 0;
      if (!(is >> std::hex >> inbound_data_size))
      {
        // Header doesn't seem to be valid. Inform the caller.
        boost::system::error_code error(boost::asio::error::invalid_argument);
        boost::get<0>(handler)(error);
        return;
      }

      // Start an asynchronous call to receive the data.
      inbound_data_.resize(inbound_data_size);
      void (connection::*f)(
          const boost::system::error_code&,
          T&, boost::tuple<Handler>)
        = &connection::handle_read_data<T, Handler>;
      boost::asio::async_read(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(inbound_data_),
        boost::bind(f, this,
          boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::ref(t), handler));
    }
  }

  /// Handle a completed read of message data.
  template <typename T, typename Handler>
  void handle_read_data(const boost::system::error_code& e,
      T& t, boost::tuple<Handler> handler)
  {
    if (e)
    {
      boost::get<0>(handler)(e);
    }
    else
    {
      // Extract the data structure from the data just received.
      try
      {
        std::string archive_data(&inbound_data_[0], inbound_data_.size());
        std::istringstream archive_stream(archive_data);
        boost::archive::text_iarchive archive(archive_stream);
        archive >> t;
      }
      catch (std::exception& e)
      {
        // Unable to decode data.
        boost::system::error_code error(boost::asio::error::invalid_argument);
        boost::get<0>(handler)(error);
        return;
      }

      // Inform caller that data has been received ok.
      boost::get<0>(handler)(e);
    }
  }

private:
  /// The underlying socket.
  boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket_;

  /// The size of a fixed length header.
  enum { header_length = 8 };

  /// Holds an outbound header.
  std::string outbound_header_;

  /// Holds the outbound data.
  std::string outbound_data_;

  /// Holds an inbound header.
  char inbound_header_[header_length];

  /// Holds the inbound data.
  std::vector<char> inbound_data_;
};

typedef boost::shared_ptr<connection> connection_ptr;

} // namespace s11n_example

#endif // SERIALIZATION_CONNECTION_HPP
```

Answer (score 0):

Like last time, this function makes no sense:

```
    template <typename Archive>
        void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version)
        {
            int a;
            int b;
        }
```

It just declares to integers and doesn't even *touch* the archive. Like before the fix for that is to ... serialize the data:

```
struct Packet {
    int a, b;
    template <typename Ar>
        void serialize(Ar& ar, unsigned) { ar& a& b; }
};
```

Also, [like last time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73751843/trying-to-do-serialization-with-struct#comment130243389_73751843), you're using a very old version of the sample:

> 1.49 is very old. It's very unlikely that's actually the version you are using. Try a more recent version (like https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples/cpp03_examples.html#boost_asio.examples.cpp03_examples.serialization) or the one matching your version of boost.